# In app purchased shared across apps with a different ID?

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

Can in-app purchase be available from different apps? I want to enable in-app purchase on a few different apps where the same non-consumable product catalog is available in all of the apps.

I assume I can create separate product ids for each app, but this will lead to duplicate data entry and make stats tracking more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No way for that, since each in-app purchase dependend on application for which it was created.